# Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, redis

im trying to run my application via interconnection with redis, i did the load balancing with nginx, i try to interconnect 3 chat apis, when i run **docker-compose up** for the first time my application works fine. but when i stop and rerun my containters with **docker-compse up** i get following error for minimum one of my chat client applications:

```
 node:events:505
spaceship_enterprise_1  |       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
spaceship_enterprise_1  |       ^
spaceship_enterprise_1  |
spaceship_enterprise_1  | Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 172.29.0.6:6379
spaceship_enterprise_1  |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1195:16)
spaceship_enterprise_1  | Emitted 'error' event on RedisAdapter instance at:
spaceship_enterprise_1  |     at RedisClient.onError (/node_modules/socket.io-redis/dist/index.js:65:22)
spaceship_enterprise_1  |     at RedisClient.emit (node:events:527:28)
spaceship_enterprise_1  |     at RedisClient.on_error (/node_modules/socket.io-redis/node_modules/redis/index.js:342:14)
spaceship_enterprise_1  |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/socket.io-redis/node_modules/redis/index.js:223:14)
spaceship_enterprise_1  |     at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
spaceship_enterprise_1  |     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
spaceship_enterprise_1  |     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
spaceship_enterprise_1  |     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
spaceship_enterprise_1  |   errno: -113,
spaceship_enterprise_1  |   code: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
spaceship_enterprise_1  |   syscall: 'connect',
spaceship_enterprise_1  |   address: '172.29.0.6',
spaceship_enterprise_1  |   port: 6379
spaceship_enterprise_1  | }
spaceship_enterprise_1  |
```

my docker-compose.yml:

```
version : '3.2'

services:

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - chatnetworks

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./DockerfileNginx 
    volumes_from:
      - nostromo
      - millennium_falcon
      - spaceship_enterprise
     
    ports:
      - "4001:4001"

    networks:
      - chatnetworks
    
  
   

  userdb:
    image: mongo:latest 
    container_name: mongodb
    volumes:
      - userdb:/data/db
    networks:
      - chatnetworks

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    container_name: prometheus
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus:/etc/prometheus
      - prometheus-data:/prometheus
    command: --web.enable-lifecycle  --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    networks:
      - chatnetworks

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest 
    container_name: grafana
    restart: always 
    volumes: 
      - ./grafana/grafana.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini
      - ./grafana/provisioning:/etc/grafana/provisioning
      - ./grafana/data:/var/lib/grafana
    user: "1000"
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - chatnetworks

  nostromo:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile 
    ports: 
      - '4000'
    restart: 'on-failure'
    networks:
      - chatnetworks  
   
    environment: 
      - APPID=Nostromo


  millennium_falcon:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile 
    ports: 
      - '4000'
    restart: 'on-failure'
    networks:
      - chatnetworks  
 
    environment: 
      - APPID=Millennium_Falcon


  spaceship_enterprise:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile 
    ports: 
      - '4000'
    restart: 'on-failure'
    networks:
      - chatnetworks  
 
    environment: 
      - APPID=RaumschiffEnterprise


volumes:
  userdb:
  prometheus-data:
 
networks:
  chatnetworks:
```

nginx.conf

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 1; 
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid; 

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    
    default_type  application/octet-stream;


    log_format upstreamlog  '$server_name to: $upstream_addr [$request] '
                            'msec $msec request_time $request_time'
                            'processed by $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for'
                            '$remote_addr'
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;



    upstream nginxServer {
        #ip_hash;
        hash $remote_addr consistent;
        
        server spaceship_enterprise:4000;
        server nostromo:4000;
        server millennium_falcon:4000;

        #server 192.168.192.8:4000;
        #server 192.168.192.9:4000;
        #server 192.168.192.7:4000;    

    }

    server {
        listen 4001;
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name ChatClient_nginx;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log upstreamlog;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error-ssl.log;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        keepalive_timeout 70;

        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert/key.pem;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert/cert.pem;
       

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;


        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;

            proxy_pass https://nginxServer;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
}
```

i integrate redis in my server.js like:

```
....
const { createAdapter } = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(createAdapter({ host: 'redis', port: 6379 }));

....
```

Comment: What's the exact set of commands you're running to stop and restart the containers?  (Do you need to stop them?)  If your application containers need Redis to be running, does adding `depends_on: [redis]` cause it to start on the restart?

Comment: @DavidMaze im stopping the application gracefully via strg + c and run again docker-compose up, but i cant reproduce the error after i added your advice, ty